# iOS 7 like semi transparent blurred view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I'm trying to put a semi transparent image with blur effect behind my main view, similar to how Apple is doing in iOS 7. What is the best, most efficient way of going about this sort of effect?

Comment: The *most* efficient way would be to search for an existing question before posting a new one.

Comment: There are already many way available on internet. First check that and try. and if you face any problem in that than ask here : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ios7

Comment: This sample project may help you.https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Answer (score 6):

This is the best one I've come across: [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)